# How to find combinations of values in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this

| Single Client Index | Nation | Status | Client Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UK | Active | abc |
| 1 | Sweden | Inactive | aab |
| 1 | Germany | Inactive | bba |
| 2 | Poland | Active | rge |
| 2 | Australia | Active | erg |
| 2 | Denmark | Inactive | asj |
| 3 | Norway | Inactive | fjw |
| 3 | Sweden | Inactive | hjs |
| 4 | Bahrain | Inactive | isg |
| 4 | Bahrain | Inactive | ejs |
| 5 | USA | Active | mt4 |
| 5 | USA | Active | whw |

And I need to turn it into something that looks like this

| Single Client Index | Nation/Status Mix |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | One Active Nation, Rest Inactive |
| 2 | Multiple Active Nations |
| 3 | All Nations Inactive |
| 4 | All Clients Inactive, Same Nation |
| 5 | All Clients Active, Same Nation |

I have no idea how to approach this. I can pivot on the single client index, but how can I get the conditional logic over the "if exists" element of the nation/status field combos?

I am only a beginner with Python but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like you want something like `df.groupby('Single Client Index')` and then work that in multiple ways, maybe involving `.value_counts()`, but I haven't worked it out so I'm hazy on the details.

Comment: IIUC, you can indeed use a `pivot_table` (see my answer below) considering the cases zero country / one country / >1 country for each Active/Inactive. This yields 9 combinations and your example only demonstrates 5 of them. Can you elaborate on the exact logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this gets you started.

```
import  pandas as pd

data = [
[1,'UK','Active','abc'],
[1,'Sweden','Inactive','aab'],
[1,'Germany','Inactive','bba'],
[2,'Poland','Active','rge'],
[2,'Australia','Active','erg'],
[2,'Denmark','Inactive','asj'],
[3,'Norway','Inactive','fjw'],
[3,'Sweden','Inactive','hjs'],
[4,'Bahrain','Inactive','isg'],
[4,'Bahrain','Inactive','ejs'],
[5,'USA','Active','mt4'],
[5,'USA','Active','whw']
]

df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['Client Index','Nation','Status','Client Name'] )
print(df)

def classify(info):
    if not info['Active']:
        if len(info['Inactive']) > 1:
            return 'All Nations Inactive'
        else:
            return 'One Nation, All Inactive'
    elif len(info['Active']) == 1:
        if not info['Inactive']:
            return 'One Nation, All Active'
        else:
            return 'One Active Nation, Rest Inactive'
    else:
        if not info['Inactive']:
            return 'All Nations Active'
        else:
            return 'Multiple Nations Active'


active = {'Active': set(), 'Inactive': set()}
last = 0
result = []
for _index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Client Index'] != last:
        if last:
            result.append( [last, classify(active)] )
        last = row['Client Index']
        active = {'Active': set(), 'Inactive': set()}
    active[row['Status']].add( row['Nation'] )
result.append( [last, classify(active)] )

df1 = pd.DataFrame( result, columns=['Client Index','Status'])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    Client Index     Nation    Status Client Name
0              1         UK    Active         abc
1              1     Sweden  Inactive         aab
2              1    Germany  Inactive         bba
3              2     Poland    Active         rge
4              2  Australia    Active         erg
5              2    Denmark  Inactive         asj
6              3     Norway  Inactive         fjw
7              3     Sweden  Inactive         hjs
8              4    Bahrain  Inactive         isg
9              4    Bahrain  Inactive         ejs
10             5        USA    Active         mt4
11             5        USA    Active         whw
   Client Index                            Status
0             1  One Active Nation, Rest Inactive
1             2           Multiple Nations Active
2             3              All Nations Inactive
3             4          One Nation, All Inactive
4             5            One Nation, All Active
```

Comment: This works beautifully. I don't fully understand the second block of code...in particular the active = {'Active': set(), 'Inactive': set()}. Is this just creating a dictionary with an empty set?

Comment: It's creating a  structure where I can collect all of the active and inactive clients.  For each client index, I gather up the names of the nations that are active and inactive.  I used a dictionary so I could avoid "if status == 'Active': / `activeList.append(nation)`.  When the client index changes, I need to save the accumulator and clear it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) to count the number of unique Active/Inactive and [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) with `upper=2` to get 0/1/2 categories (9 total combinations, you could also use `cut` if more categories are expected) and map the values from a matrix of labels using a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
labels = ['One Active Nation, Rest Inactive',  # 0
          'Multiple Active Nations',           # 1
          'All Nations Inactive',              # 2
          'All Clients Inactive, Same Nation', # 3
          'All Clients Active, Same Nation',   # 4
         ]

x = float('nan')

         # Inactive:     0  1  >1   # Active
matrix = (pd.DataFrame([[x, 3, 2],  # 0
                        [4, 0, 0],  # 1
                        [2, 1, 1],  # >1
                       ])
            .rename_axis(index='Active', columns='Inactive')
         )

out = (df
   .pivot_table(index='Client Index', columns='Status', values='Nation',
                aggfunc='nunique', fill_value=0)
   .clip(upper=2)
   .reset_index()
   .merge(matrix.stack().rename('Nation/Status Mix')
                .map(dict(enumerate(labels))),
          left_on=['Active', 'Inactive'], right_index=True,
          how='left'
         )
)
```

I believe such an approach is explicit since you have to define the mapping for all existing combinations of possibilities.

Output:

```
   Client Index  Active  Inactive                  Nation/Status Mix
0             1       1         2   One Active Nation, Rest Inactive
1             2       2         1            Multiple Active Nations
2             3       0         2               All Nations Inactive
3             4       0         1  All Clients Inactive, Same Nation
4             5       1         0    All Clients Active, Same Nation
```

The `matrix` is a condensed way of getting this kind of mapping:

```
matrix.applymap(dict(enumerate(labels)).get)

Inactive                                0                                  1                                 2
Active                                                                                                        
0                                    None  All Clients Inactive, Same Nation              All Nations Inactive
1         All Clients Active, Same Nation   One Active Nation, Rest Inactive  One Active Nation, Rest Inactive
2                    All Nations Inactive            Multiple Active Nations           Multiple Active Nations
```